# Dismissing presenting modal ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController`, which presents a modal ViewController. From within this modal ViewController I want to present a `MailComposeViewController`. My problem is during dismissal. I want to dismiss both displayed `ViewController` at the same time.

My predecessor grabbed an instance of the `presentingViewController`, send a message to display the `MailComposeViewController` and dismissed the modal ViewController all in the `BaseViewController`.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                            completion:^{
                                 [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];
```

I currently try to prevent this, as it is a godclass (over 5kloc) and I need to tear it apart.

So I tried to use the same pattern in my modal ViewController, but used `self.presentingViewController`instead. This resulted in just dismissing the modal ViewController, but not displaying anything.

Grabbing an instance prior to dismissal worked, but the delegate callback for dismissal is ignored (no wonder, as the modal ViewController is not displayed anymore).

So going into the delegate callback `- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*) controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult) result error:(NSError*) error`

I tried to dismiss the modal ViewController prior to the `MailComposeViewController` without an animation. This also removes the `MailComposeViewController` (also no surprise). I could dismiss first the `MailComposeViewController` and then the modal ViewController, but this creates a different animation in which the controllers are dismissed at a different time and order (and we all know how UX reacts to something like that ;)).

So are there any other options, in which I can dismiss first the modal ViewController and then display the `MailComposeViewController`, without having any dismissal code in the `BaseViewController`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.

On the other hand the presenting view controller of course is responsible for presenting. So there is no way presenting a new view controller without having any dismissal code in the `BaseViewController` which in your case the presenting view controller

you can dismiss without animate then present the new one

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO
                         completion:^{
                               [self presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was wrong about grabbing an instance of `presentingViewController` and using this. I just have to use it everywhere. So I ended up with this code for dismissing the `modal ViewController` and displaying the `MailComposeViewController`:

```
self.presenter = self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                             completion:^{
                                 [self.presenter presentViewController:mailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }];
```

To dismiss the `MailComposeViewController` I call: `[self.presenter dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` in the delegateMethod.